# Function doesn't return the right Boolean value

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, boolean

Having realized that recursion is one of my weak points I found a website that forces you to solve simple problems recursively (https://codestepbystep.com/problem/view/cpp/recursion/digitsSorted?problemsetid=15)

The one I'm stuck with (digitsSorted, number 5) goes as follows: you call a function passing a number as an argument. If the digits in that number are sorted in increasing order, the function returns True, otherwise returns False. Duplicate digits are allowed. The function should be also able to handle negative numbers. A single digit is sorted by definition.

So func(0), func(112234) or func(-345669) returns True, but func(4321) returns False, and so on.

To force you use recursion there is a series of constraints: no loops, no global variables, no date structures but as many variables as you want, and you can't use a string to solve it either.

My code is:

```
def digitsSorted(x):
    if x < 0:
        x = x * (-1)
        digitsSorted(x)
    elif (x/10) < 1:
        return True 
    else:
        remainder1 =  x % 10
        x = (x - remainder1) / 10
        remainder2 = x % 10
        if remainder1 >= remainder2:
            digitsSorted(x)
        else:
            return False
```

When I call the function I only get the right answer when the argument is a single digit, otherwise it returns None. However I think the code is correct because when I change:

```
return True
```

for:

```
print(True)
return
```

and the same with the line "return False", the code works as it should. I just can't work out what the problem is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your debugger say when you step through it?

Comment: Hey there. I've been coding just for a few weeks, so I'm afraid I don't really know how to use the debugger

Comment: figuring out how to use a debugger is invaluable for complex code and learning why certain things are happening (e.g. tracking down and solving bugs)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've just checked "The Python Debugger" on the official documentation and looks pretty intimidating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In recursion, when you "re-call" the function, you have to return it's result to the original function.

Your code is fine. It just needs one minor change:

```
def digitsSorted(x):
    if x < 0:
        x = x * (-1)
        return digitsSorted(x)
    elif x < 10:
        return True
    else:
        remainder1 = x % 10
        x = int(x / 10)
        remainder2 = x % 10
        if remainder1 >= remainder2:
            return  digitsSorted(x)
        else:
            return False
```

The change you have to do is when you call the function recursively: `return digitsSorted(x)`

I have also made a few minor changes while i was editing your code which you don't need to use for your program to work.

Comment: This is the case for any function, whether recursive or not.

Comment: Glad I helped. You might want to give me the check mark if my answer worked for you.

Comment: You claim to know this, but went out of your way to tie it to recursion in your answer.

Comment: @ScottHunter to be fair, if the called function is not intended to produce the return value, `return`ing it would not be correct.

Comment: You would still have to return *something*; again, having nothing to do with recursion.